# How Can I Create A Folder Here?

Tags: android, directory

I can't seem to "find" the path to this parent folder on my phone.
The first image is what Windows Explorer says my phone memory looks like.
The second image is what Total Commander says my phone memory looks like.

I have tried many combinations "Internal shared storage", with and without "storage", "0", "emulated", etc.

[image: I want to create a new folder among these]

[image: This is what the app Total Commander says my memory looks like]

Comment: Please clarify. Do You need to create folder programmatically? You need to get list of folders on internal memory?

Comment: Yes, I want to create a folder.  If it is in the parent folder in the first image I can drag and drop files with Windows.  For example, if the new folder is "Marque" I would hope to find it between "fonts" and "Movies" in the first image.  Then I could drag and drop files from windows and the phone.

Comment: That is what the Android SDK refers to as [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/14/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File directory = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + YOUR_DIR_NAME);
boolean dirOk = directory.mkdirs();
if (dirOk){
// dir created successfully
}else{
//dir create failed
}
```

In the manifest add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: This is my AndroidManifest.xml:

Comment: Overstayed my 5 minute timer.  Manifest: This is my AndroidManifest.xml:     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />  I don't have an sdCard, I'm using internal memory.  I got the directory /storage/emulated/0/fileOut.txt  but I get "java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/fileOut.txt (Permission denied)"

Comment: I don't have an sdCard, I'm using internal memory. I got the directory /storage/emulated/0/fileOut.txt but I get "java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/fileOut.txt (Permission denied)"